# How to Draw a Outline (Edge ) of Irregular Shape using c#

Tags: c#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h85Q9.jpg)

Please give me a solution about that  I have ti find out many site's but  i did not get any solution. 
thankyou

Comment: Look into the `GraphicsPath` object and `DrawPath` method

Comment: Thank you For your Advice Sir , but can you share me a code because i do not know about it.

Comment: There are so many examples of using Graphics.DrawPath(..GraphicsPath) out there that you ought to find one. We are not here to do all the work. When you have code and queston do come back!

Comment: thakyou sir I got it

Answer (score 0):

```
     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(@"D:\shapes_Images\4.png");
        pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
        image = bitmap ;
    }
    Bitmap image;
    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {


        //Create a path and add lines.
        List<Point> outlinePoints = new List<Point>();

        BitmapData bitmapData = image.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        byte[] originalBytes = new byte[image.Width * image.Height * 4];
        Marshal.Copy(bitmapData.Scan0, originalBytes, 0, originalBytes.Length);
        //find non-transparent pixels visible from the top of the image
        for (int x = 0; x < bitmapData.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < bitmapData.Height; y++)
            {
                byte alpha = originalBytes[y * bitmapData.Stride + 4 * x + 3];

                if (alpha != 0)
                {
                    Point p = new Point(x, y);

                    if (!ContainsPoint(outlinePoints, p))
                        outlinePoints.Add(p);

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        //helper variable for storing position of the last pixel visible from both sides 
        //or last inserted pixel
        int? lastInsertedPosition = null;
        //find non-transparent pixels visible from the right side of the image
        for (int y = 0; y < bitmapData.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = bitmapData.Width - 1; x >= 0; x--)
            {
                byte alpha = originalBytes[y * bitmapData.Stride + 4 * x + 3];

                if (alpha != 0)
                {
                    Point p = new Point(x, y);

                    if (!ContainsPoint(outlinePoints, p))
                    {
                        if (lastInsertedPosition.HasValue)
                        {
                            outlinePoints.Insert(lastInsertedPosition.Value + 1, p);
                            lastInsertedPosition += 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            outlinePoints.Add(p);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //save last common pixel from visible from more than one sides
                        lastInsertedPosition = outlinePoints.IndexOf(p);
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        lastInsertedPosition = null;
        //find non-transparent pixels visible from the bottom of the image
        for (int x = bitmapData.Width - 1; x >= 0; x--)
        {
            for (int y = bitmapData.Height - 1; y >= 0; y--)
            {
                byte alpha = originalBytes[y * bitmapData.Stride + 4 * x + 3];

                if (alpha != 0)
                {
                    Point p = new Point(x, y);

                    if (!ContainsPoint(outlinePoints, p))
                    {
                        if (lastInsertedPosition.HasValue)
                        {
                            outlinePoints.Insert(lastInsertedPosition.Value + 1, p);
                            lastInsertedPosition += 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            outlinePoints.Add(p);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //save last common pixel from visible from more than one sides
                        lastInsertedPosition = outlinePoints.IndexOf(p);
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        lastInsertedPosition = null;
        //find non-transparent pixels visible from the left side of the image
        for (int y = bitmapData.Height - 1; y >= 0; y--)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < bitmapData.Width; x++)
            {
                byte alpha = originalBytes[y * bitmapData.Stride + 4 * x + 3];

                if (alpha != 0)
                {
                    Point p = new Point(x, y);

                    if (!ContainsPoint(outlinePoints, p))
                    {
                        if (lastInsertedPosition.HasValue)
                        {
                            outlinePoints.Insert(lastInsertedPosition.Value + 1, p);
                            lastInsertedPosition += 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            outlinePoints.Add(p);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //save last common pixel from visible from more than one sides
                        lastInsertedPosition = outlinePoints.IndexOf(p);
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Added to close the loop
        outlinePoints.Add(outlinePoints[0]);

        image.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

        GraphicsPath myPath = new GraphicsPath();

        myPath.AddLines(outlinePoints.ToArray());
       // return outlinePoints.ToArray();
        PathGradientBrush pthGrBrush = new PathGradientBrush(outlinePoints.ToArray());
        //foreach (Point p in outlinePoints.ToArray())
        //{
        //    //Point p1 = p;

        //}
        Color[] colors = { Color.Red , Color.Green  };
        pthGrBrush.SurroundColors = colors;
        pthGrBrush.CenterColor = Color.Red;   
        Blend blend = new Blend();
       // blend.Factors = new float[] { 1, 0 };
        blend.Positions = new float[] { 0, 0.25f };
        pthGrBrush.Blend = blend;
       // LinearGradientBrush linGrBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(new Point(0, 10),new Point(200, 10),Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0),Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255));  
        e.Graphics.FillPath(pthGrBrush, myPath);   
      //  Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 6);
       // e.Graphics.DrawPath(pthGrBrush, myPath);

    }
```